# ENOENT: dist folder can't be generated by both ng build and ng serve

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ng-build, enoent

When I run the angular commands `ng build` or `ng serve`, I get the following error and the dist folder is not generated:

> An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\khins\Desktop\EcommerceAngular\Ecommerce\dist'
> See "C:\Users\khins\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-MzMpV6\angular-errors.log" for further details.

Angular CLI: 13.3.3
Node: 14.17.6
Package Manager: npm 6.14.15
OS: win32 x64

angular.json:

```
   "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/Ecommerce",
            "index": "src/index.html",
```

package.json:

```
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
```

I added ngx-bootstrap 8.0.0.0

Comment: `ng serve` does not generate files into the dist folder, could you please add to the question the contents of the file `C:\Users\khins\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-MzMpV6\angular-errors.log` ?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the exact same problem using Angular 13.3.9, ngx-bootstrap 8, bootstrap 5.1.3.